# What is algebraic about ADT in functional programming?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

In a Scala book I read this:

> For example, this code is an ADT:
>
> ```scala
> sealed trait Bool 
> case object True extends Bool 
> case object False extends Bool
> ```

....and further it says:

> The “algebra” in ADTs is described on the Haskell wiki like this:
>
> > “Algebraic” refers to the property that an Algebraic Data Type is created by “algebraic” operations. The “algebra” here is “sums” and “products” (of types).

But where are those 'algebraic' operations in code snippet above?

Comment: I have no knowledge of Scala but the code seems like a sum-type. The `Bool` is the sum of `True` and `False`.

Comment: Without context, you could probably read "ADT" as abstract data type as well.

Comment: Here's an excellent introduction to ADTs: http://tomasp.net/blog/types-and-math.aspx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boolean type can be views as the sum of the unit type and the unit type. Apologies for writing the following in Haskell rather than Scala:

```
type MyBool = Either () ()
```

Since `()` has only a single value, the type `Either () ()` has only two values, based on whether we use `Left` or `Right` on `()` to construct a value.

The proof that `Bool` and `Either () ()` are isomorphic follows:

We can define two functions for converting `Bool` to an `Either () ()` or vice versa.

```
b2e :: Bool -> Either () ()
b2e True = Right ()
b2e False = Left ()

e2b :: Either () () -> Bool
e2b (Right ()) = True
e2b (Left ()) = False
```

And we can trivially show that `b2e` and `e2b` are isomorphisms.

```
e2b (b2e True) == e2b (Right ()) == True
e2b (b2e False) == e2b (Left ()) == False
b2e (e2b (Right ())) == b2e True == Right ()
b2e (e2b (Left ())) == b2e False == Left ()
```

Thus `e2b . b2e == b2e . e2b == id`.

Answer (score 6):

> But where are those 'algebraic' operations in code snippet above?

They are implicit in the syntax of the language. The conceptual operation of "addition"

```
A + B
```

can be encoded in Scala as

```
sealed trait T 
case object A extends T 
case object B extends T
```

whilst conceptual operation of multiplication

```
A x B
```

can be encoded in Scala as

```
case class T(a: A, b: B)
```

> What is algebraic about ADT

The term "algebra" has roots in mathematical field called [abstract algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra). It is an endeavour which looks into different objects and different operations on those objects and hopes to find common behaviours between them. Roughly it is the process of taking away things and seeing what remains. Like when you learn to count and do arithmetic with apples as a child. At some point you "take away" the apples, and what remains are "numbers" which behave the same way as apples. The advantage of that is that now the same rules and laws you learned with arithmetic of apples, generalise to arithmetic of oranges and beyond. But mathematicians go even further and ask crazy question like what happens if we take away even the numbers themselves? Another way of looking at it is you write down some equation like

```sh
a + b = b + a       (commutativity law)
```

where addition `+` is defined in some abstract sense, and now try to find any kind of object that satisfy it. For example, integers satisfy it, as well as real numbers, etc., but turns out also certain kind of data types like sum types fit into that equation. So then mathematicians declare all the classes of objects, collectively, which work with addition operation in some sense, such that the result of the operation is commutative, as an algebraic structure, and give it some grand name like Abelian group etc. This is roughly the etymology of "algebraic" in "algebraic data type".

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell you can write an ADT also with the *generalized* ADT syntax:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Bool where
  False :: Bool
  True :: Bool
```

...which looks more like the Scala version, than the equivalent standard-Haskell notation does:

```hs
data Bool = False | True
```

As for how this is algebraic: `Bool` is an example of a *sum type*. The most general one of these is

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, GADTs #-}

data (+) a b where
  Left :: a -> (a+b)
  Right :: b -> (a+b)
```

the standard version of which is

```hs
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

The generic *product* type would be

```hs
data (*) a b where
  Both :: a -> b -> (a*b)
```

which is isomorphic to `(a,b)`.

Now you could define some finite types:

```hs
data One = One
type Two = One + One
type Three = One + Two
type Four = Two * Two
```

etc. etc.. As an exercise, prove that each of these has exactly as many different legal values as the name suggests.